# Can't override styles using classes in material-ui

Tags: material-ui

I am having a hell of a time trying to understand how to change the styles for a one time use of `TextField`

The docs really don't make any sense to me

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel
    htmlFor="mobile-number-input"
  >
    Mobile Number
  </InputLabel>
  <Input
    value={this.state.mobileNumber}
    onChange={this.onMobileNumberChange}
    fullWidth
    classes={{
      inkbar: {
        '&:after': {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        }
      }
    }}
    id="mobile-number-input"
  />
</FormControl><br />
```

But I get this error

```
Warning: Material-UI: the key `inkbar` provided to the classes property is not valid for Input.
You need to provide a non empty string instead of: [object Object].
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to override `inkbar` with the name of another class, not a JSS object.

One way of doing this is to declare your JSS object outside of the component and use the `withStyles` higher-order component to provide your component with a `classes` prop that maps the class names defined in JSS to their actual names:

```js
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

const styles = {
  inkbarOverride: {
    '&:after': {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    }
  }
};

const Test = ({ classes }) =>
  <FormControl>
    <InputLabel
      htmlFor="mobile-number-input"
    >
      Mobile Number
    </InputLabel>
    <Input
      value={this.state.mobileNumber}
      onChange={this.onMobileNumberChange}
      fullWidth
      classes={{
        inkbar: classes.inkbarOverride,
      }}
      id="mobile-number-input"
    />
  </FormControl>

export default withStyles(styles)(Test);
```

Refer to [Overriding with classes](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) for more information.